# How to get sqldb to use a particular fbclient.dll?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I'm using sqldb to connect to Firebird from within my DLL. This fails because it cannot find fbclient.dll which is actually present in the same directory as my DLL. `GetCurrentDir` returns the path to the Windows system folder. Performing a `SetCurrentDir` with the path of the DLL successfully changes the current directory, but still it won't work. What can I do to get sqldb to use fbclient.dll at a location of my choosing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`the wiki page`](http://wiki.freepascal.org/firebird#Windows) seems there is no way to explicitly specify the directory from where the Firebird client library could be loaded. So as a workaround you may use the [`SetDllDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which will add a directory provided to its only parameter to the search path used to locate DLL libraries for the application. A subsequent call to [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function used to load the Firebird's client library will go through the search list and find it in the location you added by the [`SetDllDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function call.